# Using Boost find_last to find any of

Tags: c++, boost, find

This is a function which returns a pointer to the filename portion in a C-string path.
`StringT` is supposed to be either `char*` or `wchar_t*`.

```
template <typename StringT>
StringT GetFilenamePos(StringT path) {
    typedef boost::iterator_range<typename boost::range_iterator<StringT>::type> StringItRange;
    StringItRange lastFound = boost::find_last(path, L"\\");
    StringT filename = lastFound.empty()
                        ? path
                        : lastFound.end();
    return filename;
}
```

I would like to search not only for `\`, but also for `/`, is there a way to construct a finder object with Boost that does this in one string traversal (like `find_any_of`)?

I would like to do this in one search traversal and without any copying.

As a second, less important point; is there a way to change the `L"\\"` literal so that either a wide or a normal literal is chosen, depending on the template argument?

Comment: For your second point would [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c6b78433edf79ecd) do? (credit goes to [Steve Jessop's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4100783/583833) if it does)

Comment: Is the [std::string::find_last_of](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_last_of/) a solution?

Comment: @megabyte1024 I want a pointer to the start of the filename in an existing C string, which this cannot do, but otherwise it does exactly what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE 2** As Pascal once said:

> "I have made this letter longer than usual, because I lack the time to make it short"

I finally found the time to make it short! Now, it doesn't require boost anymore:

### 3. Using `std::string::find_last_of`

You can use that really straightforward. It's essentially a oneliner here - except for the need to specify the set of separator characters in a character-type independent way.

In this example I choose to use `boost::string_ref` to return a user-friendly const reference to the subrange of the input string.

Note that using `boost::string_ref` is optional and doesn't require a link dependency. You can change it for `std::pair<iterator, iterator>` if you prefer:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9cf0d5fbe5a658b9)</kbd>**

```
#include <string>
#include <boost/utility/string_ref.hpp>

template <typename StringT, typename C = typename StringT::value_type>
boost::basic_string_ref<C> GetFilename(StringT const& path) {
    static const C separators[4] = { '\\', '/', ':', 0 };
    return boost::basic_string_ref<C>(path).substr(path.find_last_of(separators) + 1);
}

#include <iostream>

int main() {
    for (std::string fname : {
            "/tmp/somedir/../other//./beautiful filenames.txt.0",
            "simple.txt",
            "",
        })
    {
        std::cout << "'" << fname << "' -> '" << GetFilename(fname) << "'\n";
    }

    for (std::wstring fname : {
            L"D:\\Program Files (64)\\Something Else Entirely\\but works.just-the-same.exe",
            L"\\UNCNAME\\Something Else Entirely\\network.dat",
            L"D://testing/test123",
            L"http://user:password@hostname:port/test123/resource?query=parameter#yo"
            L"E:beautiful filenames.txt.0",
            L"simple.txt",
            L"",
        })
    {
        std::wcout << "'" << fname << "' -> '" << GetFilename(fname) << "'\n";
    }
}
```

Prints

```
'/tmp/somedir/../other//./beautiful filenames.txt.0' -> 'beautiful filenames.txt.0'
'simple.txt' -> 'simple.txt'
'' -> ''
'D:\Program Files (64)\Something Else Entirely\but works.just-the-same.exe' -> 'but works.just-the-same.exe'
'\UNCNAME\Something Else Entirely\network.dat' -> 'network.dat'
'D://testing/test123' -> 'test123'
'http://user:password@hostname:port/test123/resource?query=parameter#yo' -> 'resource?query=parameter#yo'
'E:beautiful filenames.txt.0' -> 'beautiful filenames.txt.0'
'simple.txt' -> 'simple.txt'
'' -> ''
```

**UPDATE** Since you desire no-copy behaviour, here's a version that uses Boost Regex

### 2. Using Boost Regex

This solution too returns a `string_ref` of the appropriate character type.

Turns out this approach was much more heavy-handed than required, but you might still like to see/use it for less trivial tasks.

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ebe475aa33a3ce4d)**

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <boost/utility/string_ref.hpp>

template <typename StringT, typename C = typename StringT::value_type>
boost::basic_string_ref<C> GetFilename(StringT const& path) {

    // it's quite tricky to initialze the pattern generically:
    static auto re = [] {
        char const pattern[] = "[^\\\\/:]*$";
        std::basic_string<C> spattern(pattern, pattern + sizeof(pattern)-1);
        return boost::basic_regex<C>(spattern, boost::regex_constants::optimize);
    }();

    // the rest is plain sailing:
    boost::match_results<typename StringT::const_iterator> mr;
    if (boost::regex_search(path.begin(), path.end(), mr, re) && mr[0].matched)
        return { &*(mr[0].first), size_t(mr[0].length()) };
    return path;
}

#include <iostream>

int main() {

    std::string fname = "/tmp/somedir/../other//./beautiful filenames.txt.0";
    std::cout << GetFilename(fname) << "\n";
    std::wstring wname = L"D:\\Program Files (64)\\Something Else Entirely\\but works.just-the-same.exe";
    std::wcout << GetFilename(wname) << "\n";
}
```

Prints:

```
beautiful filenames.txt.0
but works.just-the-same.exe
```

### 1. Using Boost FileSystem

The old answer was: This seems like a job for Boost Filesystem.

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/04a01bcb466a03bc)**

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace fs = boost::filesystem;

template <typename StringT>
StringT GetFilename(StringT const& path) {
    return fs::path(path).filename().string<StringT>();
}

int main() {
#ifndef _WIN32
    std::string fname = "/tmp/somedir/../other//./beautiful filenames.txt.0";
    std::cout << GetFilename(fname) << "\n";
#else
    std::wstring wname = L"D:\\Program Files (64)\\Something Else Entirely\\but works.just-the-same.exe";
    std::wcout << GetFilename(wname) << "\n";
#endif
}
```

This should print

```
beautiful filenames.txt.0
```

or

```
but works.just-the-same.exe
```

depending on your platform

Comment: Nice and short, but I do want a simple, one-traversal, search that gives me a pointer into the existing string. This will be used in a loop with possibly hundreds of thousands of files; I would like to avoid any copying.

Comment: Good point. I didn't get that because you had the return type `StringT`

Comment: @FelixDombek Added a generic, non-copying implementation with a userfriendly interface, based on Boost Regex. I'm pretty sure it can be made shorter and more efficient using Boost String Algorithms instead, but sadly I lack the time right now

Comment: @FelixDombek **Good news:** I found the time to simplify it further. It's now essentially a oneliner requiring only the standard library. ***[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9cf0d5fbe5a658b9)***

Comment: Thanks, awesome. I'm not sure that using a colon as separator is such a good idea, because (1) where do paths like `E:file.txt` actually occur and (2) it is also the named stream separator symbol. But this solution is exactly what I was looking for.